# How to tell tensorflow that order doesn't matter

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have 5 arrays of 10 values each I currently pass to tensorflow. But, after training, when I use model.predict I can get wildly different values just by changing the order of the arrays.

For example [1, 2], [3, 4] would give different results than [3,4], [1,2]. The order shouldn't matter so is there a way to tell that to tensorflow?

Here is my current code:

```
field_names = ["elo", "map", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "result"]
df_train = pd.read_csv('input/match_results.csv', names=field_names, skiprows=1, usecols=range(2, 13))
for count in range(1, 6):
    str_count = str(count)
    def converter(x):
        if isinstance(x, str):
            return pd.Series(champ_features_dict[x])
        else:
            return x

    df_train["c" + str_count] = df_train["c" + str_count].apply(converter)

    df_train['result'] = pd.Categorical(df_train['result'])
    df_train['result'] = df_train.result.cat.codes
df_train = df_train.drop(columns=['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5'], axis=1)
target = df_train.pop('result')
targets = np.array(list(x for x in target.values))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_train.values, targets))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(df_train)).batch(batch_size)

for relative_step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(train_data.take(training_steps), 1):
    run_optimization(batch_x, batch_y)
```

Comment: While trying to reproduce your issue, we got the error, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File input/match_results.csv does not exist: 'input/match_results.csv'`. Can you provide the complete reproducible code so that we can help you. Thanks!